# Print Report directly on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I got some problems with *JasperReports Server*. I need to print report directly on the server.
I view report first and then just click on the print it will open Printer Dialog. After choose printer I can print report as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried something out..?

Comment: Can you specify something out that you just mention?

Comment: I meant that have you written some code regarding your question..? If yes then edit your question and post it so that others can help you in a better manner...

Comment: How about you? Do you have any ideas how we can use those code in jasperreport server, print function for example?

Comment: I just got this solution. I use javascript code.
But I don't know it's the best solution or not.
If have any other solutions please help out.
This is the code:

var url=document.location.href+'&output=pdf';
var printWindow=window.open(url,'_blank'); 
printWindow.print();

Answer (score 0):

I just got this solution. I use javascript code.
But I don't know it's the best solution or not.
If have any other solutions please help me out.
This is the code:

```
var url=document.location.href+'&output=pdf';
var printWindow=window.open(url,'_blank'); 
printWindow.print();
```