# Cannot Pass Report to Printer

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have edited some codes in my *JasperReports Server*.
I want to pass report to the printer directly.
Now I can only out report as pdf, but cannot pass that pdf file to printer.
This is my *JavaScript* code:

```
var url = document.location.href+"&output=pdf";
var prnWindow=window.open(url);
prnWindow.print();
prnWindow.close();
```

Any ideas? Please help me. I really need your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print Report directly on JasperReports Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887689/print-report-directly-on-jasperreports-server)